# How to load split HDFS files to Oracle database?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I need to load data from split files on HDFS to Oracle database.

```
[user@asdf 007]$ hadoop dfs -ls 
hdfs://XXXXXX/split_files/test_folder/test_table_with_partitions/*
Found 18 items
drwxrwxrwx   - bigsql hdfs          0 2017-07-24 01:00 hdfs://XXXXXX/split_files/test_folder/test_table_with_partitions/tm=2017-07-24/dept=1
drwxrwxrwx   - bigsql hdfs          0 2017-07-24 01:00 hdfs://XXXXXX/split_files/test_folder/test_table_with_partitions/tm=2017-07-24/dept=2
drwxrwxrwx   - bigsql hdfs          0 2017-07-24 01:00 hdfs://XXXXXX/split_files/test_folder/test_table_with_partitions/tm=2017-07-24/dept=3
drwxrwxrwx   - bigsql hdfs          0 2017-07-24 01:00 hdfs://XXXXXX/split_files/test_folder/test_table_with_partitions/tm=2017-07-24/dept=4
drwxrwxrwx   - bigsql hdfs          0 2017-07-24 01:00 hdfs://XXXXXX/split_files/test_folder/test_table_with_partitions/tm=2017-07-24/dept=5
.......
```

If I open the files inside any folder

```
hdfs://XXXXXX/split_files/test_folder/test_table_with_partitions/tm=2017-07-24/dept=5
```

they don't have time & department information inside them. Hence when I use sqoop that information is not loaded into database table.

How can I get this information loaded into database too? Is there any option in sqoop that does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From given details it look like HDFS files you refer are from Hive table.

To export partitioned hive table to RDBMS you have to make use of  `--hcatalog-table` argument of `sqoop`. Example is given below, where test1 hive table is partitioned and is being exported to MySQL table test.test.

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.35:3306/test --username root --table test1 --hcatalog-table test1
```

To export to Oracle database you will have to replace `jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.35:3306/test` by `jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port>:<service>`

Comment: Hi Shubhangi, Thanks for the help!! That's exactly I was looking for.